# ArrayList not populating in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my AsyncTask, I use Jsoup to pull all of the p tags from a web page, and I add them to an ArrayList that *should* then be used by an ArrayAdapter to fill the screen with the posts, but for some reason, the ArrayList is empty when I go to check it after the methods.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    newsItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    fillNewsItems();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            newsItems));
    Log.d("news", Integer.toString(newsItems.size()));
}

private class GetNewsItemsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            for (Element e : doc.getElementsByTag("p")) {
                newsItems.add(e.text());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {     
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't fetch articles, try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }           
        return null;
    }
}

private void fillNewsItems() {
    GetNewsItemsTask getNews = new GetNewsItemsTask();
    getNews.execute(URL);
}
}
```

Does anyone know why the log statement in onCreate returns 0, and my list is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) has more possibilities than you are using right now. Basically the AsyncTask is a thread (which cannot change UI elements by default) but it provides a special feature: it synchronizes to the UI thread in the method `onPostExecute()`.

So you can use this to set the `ArrayAdapter` inside the `AsyncTask`. Feel free to make use of `onPreExecute()` to show an information dialog.

This code should to the trick:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    fillNewsItems();

    Log.d("news", Integer.toString(newsItems.size()));
}

private class GetNewsItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            for (Element e : doc.getElementsByTag("p")) {
                items.add(e.text());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't fetch articles, try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> items) {
        newsItems = items; // I assume that newsItems is used elsewhere.
                           // If that's not the case -> remove it
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                items));
    }
}

private void fillNewsItems() {
    GetNewsItemsTask getNews = new GetNewsItemsTask();
    getNews.execute();
}
```

This a nice tutorial about asynchronous programming in Android: [Android Threads, Handlers and AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  After removing URL from getNews.execute(), and changing newsItems to just items in the for loop, I HAVE A POPULATED LISTVIEW!!!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because the AsyncTask hasn't finished executing yet.
An AsyncTask is just that, async.  It runs in the background at the same time.
It looks like you are expecting your code to block on `fillNewsItems()` until the AsyncTask
has finished, when in reality it returns almost immediately, right after starting the AsyncTask.  So when you are trying to get the size of the list it still is zero, the AsyncTask hasn't finished yet.